# product import via csv to woocommerce with sql

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

importing products by the plugin wp all import takes too much time when sql table post_meta is growing. At the moment there are 200.000 products imported.

Is there a way to import products via csv directly in sql without wordpress.
(I do not need to import any images only titles and descriptions).

Thanks for any help in advance.

Kind regards
Oliver

Comment: Can you please explain how you did it in the end ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a 2 steps SQL.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_name`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `guid`, `post_type`, `comment_count`) 
VALUES ([ID], [AUTHOR], '[DATE1]', '[DATE2]', '[CONTENT]', '[TITLE]', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '[POSTNAME]', '[DATE3]', '[DATE4]', '[GUID]', 'product', 0);
```

I would recommend to update those records afterward using WP ALL IMPORT

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea :)
I have used remote mysql using dbforge software to import 700,000 products in 30 minutes, while the same number of products are still importing using WP all import for more than 2 weeks :)
All tests went through and i'm truly thankful for the help