# How to import woocommerce products from csv or xls to woocommerce with sql

Tags: sql, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I'm trying to import a 700000 product list to woocommerce and it's taking forever.

Is there a way to import it directly from the csv file to the SQL database?
the csv file have 5 columns:

```
Part Number=SKU 
Part Name=post_title 
Manufacturer=taxonomy:manufacturer 
Sale Price=sale_price 
Regular Price=regular_price
```

I have found an answer here but it doesn't explain how to get the data from the csv file.

[product import via csv to woocommerce with sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884387/product-import-via-csv-to-woocommerce-with-sql)

to import woocommerce products it will need to be done in both wp_posts and in wp_postmeta which is why i'm asking for help, since i'm inserting into existing tables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is th data stored?

Comment: if you mean in the csv file then it has 5 columns
Part Number=SKU
Part Name-post_title
Manufacturer=taxonomy:manufacturer
Sale Price=sale_price
Regular Price=regular_price

Comment: you can import csv files with phpmyadmin or mysqlclient directly on the server, while mysqlient is faster, as you first upload the file

Comment: please note that i'm using a shared server.
so if you can please explain how can it be done using phpmyadmin
Thanks a lot

Comment: the manual explain it quite clear https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly insert csv data into SQL by using BULK INSERT command, Syntax as follows,

```
BULK INSERT INTO TABLE
FROM '(a)'
WITH
(
ROWTERMINATOR = '(b)',
FIELDTERMINATOR = '(c)'
)
```

where,

1. a = Location of CSV file on the SQL Server, file location cannot be
   on any local machine
2. b = Escape character for line break e.g write
   \n in case rows are separated by new row
3. c = escape character for
   next column value

Please note that schema of csv file should be equal to table imported into.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.
So i will need to create 2 csv files since products are imported to 2 tables 
`wp-posts
wp-postmeta`
but how can i fix the date and time issue and the post ID in both tables ?
can i create some random 
ID's ?
Thanks

Comment: Imported within 30 minutes using dbForge mysql.
used the table import and mapping which is really fast.
Thanks a lot